# SQL Server join the last

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, join

I have the following query which used to return me counts of machines joined by their barcode. They are joined by the barcode of the line. The problem is that i may have the machine checked on several lines, and I need the last line barcode in which machine was chechecked;
example:
Machine with barcode 882102 was checked at line 99201009.
The query will return the exact count of the machines with this barcode on the line, but if the same machine was moved to line with barcode 22212302, the query will give me two rows for each of the lines. I need line 99201009 to be skipped and to get 22212302;

Here is the query:

```
SELECT rountingCode, nameBg, count(scanlog.machinebarcode) AS count 
FROM machines 
    LEFT JOIN scanlog ON scanlog.machinebarcode = machines.barcode 
              AND scanlog.linebarcode = $barcode 
ORDER BY routingCode, nameBg GROUP BY routingCode, nameBG
```

I may have mistaken something so here is the original query from codeigniter.

```
$this->db->select
  ("rountingCode, nameBg, count(scanlog.machinebarcode) AS count")->
    join("scanlog", "scanlog ON scanlog.machinebarcode = machines.barcode 
    AND scanlog.linebarcode = ".$barcode,"left")->
  order_by("routingCode")->
  group_by("routingCode, nameBg")->get("machines")->result();


ScanLog Schema
--------------
LogId
LineBarcode
ScanDate

Machines Schema
----------------
MachineId
FaNo
Barcode
Routingcode
NameBg
```

Now the query returns different row for every machine.

If I set the linebarcode to be 99201009 the query will return different row for every machine which have record in scanLog on linebarcode = 99201009;
The problem appears when some machinebarcode was checked on another line and have older checking on other line. In that case the query returns many rows for one machine.
I need one row for machine per line. But as  I said if the machine was checked at different lines and the previous record is not deleted the problem will appear and insted of 1 result per machine I will get more.
Lets say it this way:
Machine 882102 was first checked at 99201009 three times.
That means I have 3 of these machines on this line
The query will give me `count` = `3`;

Everything is okay for now.
But, when the two of the machines with barcode 882102 are moved on another line with barcode 22212302 the query will give me `count` = `2`, `count` = `1`, which is wrong for my program.
I requested line 22212302 so I have to get only `count` = `2`.

Comment: Do you have a `date_scanned` column or something similar in your tables? It would be easier to understand what you want with the schema of your tables and an example of result set that you want.

Comment: Yes I have a ScanDate field with datetime format. I will update the question with the schema in a minute :)

Comment: Could you also add a sample of result set that you want, and what you are currently getting. Somehow I am having trouble to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Its kinda hard for me explain it, english is not my native, sorry for that, But I updated the question and tried to explain it in the bottom. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT rountingCode, nameBg, count(scanlog.machinebarcode) AS count 
FROM machines 
    LEFT JOIN scanlog ON scanlog.machinebarcode = machines.barcode 
WHERE scanlog.linebarcode = $barcode
ORDER BY routingCode, nameBg GROUP BY routingCode, nameBG
```

Or you can simply use INNER JOIN.

**UPDATE**

```
select m.rountingCode,m.nameBg,
       CASE
         WHEN temp.rountingCode IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE count
       END count
from machines m
left join
(
SELECT machineid,rountingCode, nameBg, count(scanlog.machinebarcode) AS count 
FROM machines 
    LEFT JOIN scanlog ON scanlog.machinebarcode = machines.barcode 
WHERE scanlog.linebarcode = $barcode
GROUP BY routingCode, nameBG) temp
on temp.machineid=m.machineid
order by m.rountingCode,m.nameBg
```

Comment: This kinda works for me, but the problem is that I have a big html table, which i populate, so I need to get every single machine on that table, even if it doesnt exist ot that line, in that case I print zero for this machine count. :/